# How to use date and time stored in SQLite database to start an alarm notification

Tags: android, sqlite, alarm

I want to start  an alarm using the date and time stored in SQLite Database.

In the database the time and date stored in it looks like this:

> For Date format I store it like this "03/31/18" and for Time format I
>   store it like this "6:50 AM" or "PM" and  both of them are set to TEXT
>   type.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to get this data and use it to implement a alarm notification. Futhermore, is my way of storing time and date not right?

If you can look it up, please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the data by running a SELECT query that returns a Cursor.

- [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)
- [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
- [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html)

You then navigate (move) within the resultant Cursor to position to the respective row (e.g. `moveToFirst()` to go to the first row, checking the returned value false if the move could not be made, else true).

You then use the Cursor's `get????(column_offset_as_int)` methods to get the data from the respective column e.g. `getString(0)` would return the String stored in the first column. The recommended way is to not used hard coded offsets but to use the Cursor `getColumnIndex(column_name_as_a_string)` method that returns the offset/index.

When done with the Cursor you should close it using the Cursor's `close` method.

---

I'd suggest that rather than no your format for saving isn't right that rather you are storing it in a format that's not ideal and may require more code that is needed.

SQLite's date and time functions copes best with data stored as :-

> Time Strings
>
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> - YYYY-MM-DD
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> - HH:MM HH:MM:SS
> - HH:MM:SS.SSS
> - now
> - DDDDDDDDDD

- [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)